# Babel error in the twilio-chat sdk running on Nextjs

Tags: twilio, next.js, babeljs

I'm moving my app from create-react-app to Nextjs and I'm running into a weird bug when installing twilio-chat.
Every time I run the code I have this error:

```
error - ./node_modules/twilio-chat/browser/logger.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'babel-runtime/core-js/array/from' in '/sandbox/node_modules/twilio-chat/browser'
```

I created a sandbox with a basic nextjs set up to reproduce the error.
https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-solomon-25okm?file=/pages/index.js

I tried to install @babel/runtime and other packages from @babel but nothing works.
Any idea what could go wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
npm install babel-runtime
```